# Android Studio installation doesn't work with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am absolute beginner with Android Studio (especially Gradle) and having big trouble getting Android Studio to work. I downloaded and installed the most recent version of Android Studio (0.8.0). I have set the JDK_HOME variable. However, after I create a new project, I always receive the following message:

```
Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. 
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.
Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

If I try to compile the project, I get the following message dialog:

[image]

After reading a post, I manually downloaded the Gradle binaries (latest, 2.0), extracted it onto the local drive, went to Settings and set the Gradle path to the respective directory using the following:

[image]

I also tweaked the build.gradle file under the project to point to the latest Gradle 2.0 version. However, now I get the following error message:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloAndroidStudio'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.+.
Required by:
  :HelloAndroidStudio:unspecified
    Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
    Unable to load Maven meta-data from     http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
    Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
    jcenter.bintray.com
```

Please can someone help. Being my first time with Gradle, I have been trying for so many days without any clue to the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it needs to download some config file, but fails. Is the machine you're using to compile the project connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes it is. I have tried it on several machines (all connected) but fails on all.

Comment: Maybe try to run android studio with 'moderator' permission. Sometimes there are problems with showing dialog, where you can allow application to use network connection.

Comment: I am admin on all machines on which I have tried. I don't think permission is the issue here. The problem(s) is consistent on all machines.

Comment: com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+ ?

Comment: user2713030, could you elaborate. When I create a new project, that is the default under build.gradle. I only updated it to ...:0.2.0 after it didn't work.

Comment: I meant, in your `build.gradle`, replace `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.+` by `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+`

Comment: Do you have direct connection to Internet?

Comment: On one the machine, Yes its a direct connection. On the other, it's proxy based.

Comment: Do you try with a @user2713030 comment?

Comment: As i said above, that was the default. I tried other options when that failed.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Gradle version to lower ones and restart the Android Studio, you may get it.

Add this in build.gradle
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

Setting the http_proxy under appearance & behaviour -> system settings -> http proxy has solved the problem

Comment: wat should i set the http proxy to ?

Comment: with the proxy server & port number details. in IE browser, Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN settings shows the proxy details configured by your system administrator.  Sometimes it will point to a script file URL, which can be opened in the browser tab. You have to analyze and understand what is the real proxy server IP and port number.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the latest classpath in the dependencies. 
For AS 1.5.1 I will do like this :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

dependencies {
    **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'**
  }
}
```